# Is there way to specify a cloud un-init (decomission script) script like the cloud-init one?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am using cloud init to configure nodes as they come up now also need a decommissioning script to clear up some entries from remote servers. Is there an easy way to specify the decommission script like we specify the init script on node launch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not actually a `cloud-init` function as much as a linux function generally. [This question](https://superuser.com/questions/174350/execute-script-before-shutting-down-in-ubuntu) should help you run scripts on shutdown, which is what you seek.